# Time to start looking for a new job?

Tags: job-search

Current situation (Scrum Master), Senior management:

- hired new hires (Scrum Masters), I am longest serving employee
- 'forgetting' to invite me to important strategic meetings, but not forgetting to invite the other Scrum Masters. At current company Scrum Masters do a lot of agile coaching and are involved with guiding Senior management on how to improve process at team level based on feedback from Scrum Team.
- Replacing me as Scrum Master on a workstream, but reliant on me to do a 'handover' to new Scrum Master who is struggling and not acknowledging he is, or the good work I am doing to help upskill him
- Unlike other Scrum Masters, not taking a lot of my ideas/proposals seriously, reporting etc

I have spoken to Senior Management about their plans for me, their plans are the following:

- To run a new work stream at some point
- To support new Scrum Masters
- To take a step back and let them make strategic decisions which doesn't sit well from their inexperience at commercial level of this org

However, feeling a bit unsettled and undervalued since I feel that I am being deliberately brushed aside, as I am not involved in any strategic decision making without any long term plan being properly established. Feels like I have been stripped off my responsibilities, and I am now a bit anxious that they are setting me up for other people to take credit for any good work I produce. For example, after I upskill Scrum Master struggling.

Do I have any right to be concerned, should I start looking?

Comment: It feels like they are pushing you in to a more managerial role.  Are you interested in a growth in that direction?

Comment: I downvoted because I think the situation is too personal and opinionated at the moment. If you would rephrase it as a more general question it might be more suitable. Otherwise maybe a question for the chat?

Answer (score 2):

What is your exact role in the company?

Generally, a Scrum Master's job is not to make strategic decisions or propose ideas.

A Scrum Master's job but to make sure everyone in the team are fulfilling their roles, be a buffer between the team and the business owners, and to help the team sticking to scrum.

It sounds like you've either been misunderstanding your responsibilities as a Scrum-Master and thus been fulfilling other roles at the same time, without being fully aware of it, or you actually hold other positions at the same time that you've not mentioned to us. In the previous case it makes perfect sense that you're not asked to be involved in tasks that are not a part of your job.

However if you also hold a position as an architect, a team lead or a business owner of some sort (which should never be the case for Scrum-Masters but that's a different story, i.e. being a BO/PO) then it would make sense to include you in the activities you mentioned since its your responsibility to see the tasks fulfilled.

You need to be 100% sure what your responsibilities are and thus be clear on what you're being pushed out of and into. Talk to your manager and say that you've been under the impression that tasks x, y and z have been your responsibilities and you'd like him to confirm or deny those responsibilities.

If it turns out that your manager does not expect you to be working on those tasks then it's up to you to decide whether your current position, consisting of the roles assigned to you by management, is the one you want to work at. If it turns out that your manager does indeed expect you to work on the tasks you were left out on then say that you need to be involved directly in them, otherwise you can not guarantee their outcome. You

Comment: Scrum Masters are expected to do a lot of agile coaching and guide Senior Management, company is currently in an agile transformation phase. They do not just facilitate ceremonies, doing nothing else.

Comment: In that case you're also a senior manager. That's good to know, however you should be sure what exactly you're supposed to be doing. Ask your boss if the tasks you're being left out of fall within your responsibility or not and if so then tell him what needs to change in order for you to fulfill them.

Comment: Well all of my direct peers are involved (same job role), so it feels like I am.

Comment: @bobo2000 There's obviously something missing in terms of what your responsibilities are vs. what you think you should be involved in. We could play a guessing game all day in terms of assuming what you or your peers are supposed to be doing. The only one who can really answer that is your direct manager. Ideally you should have a job description that you can fall back to when in doubt. You should probably ask your boss to review your job description with you so there's no doubt in what your role/s are.